# Displaying an iframe in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to display an iframe in Dart?

Below is the code that I am using

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),  // With this highlighted text.
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I am not sure how to add an iframe into this. Below is the snippet that is given in the [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-html/IFrameElement/IFrameElement.html)

```
factory IFrameElement() => JS(
    'returns:IFrameElement;creates:IFrameElement;new:true',
    '#.createElement(#)',
    document,
    "iframe");
```

Comment: Flutter doesn't use HTML or JavaScript, so showing an IFrame in Flutter is not possible. You can use a webview plugin to show HTML in Flutter.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer and using a webview to show a local html file containing an iframe containing another local html, is it possible? 'cause the iframe never show me sthg:(

Comment: It's possible, but not wirhout some work. Local urls can not be loaded. You need to implement a tiny web server in your app and load from there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin shows HTML in Flutter. But, this plugin is currently supported in mobile but not yet for web. Here is an example of how you implement this on mobile:

Sample code using webview_flutter plugin:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev/',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Actual Output:
[image]

And regarding your question how to implement [IFrameElement](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-html/IFrameElement/IFrameElement.html). There is actually [an existing blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-and-iframe-f26399aa1e2a) where it provides all the steps to understand this. But as mentioned, this is still in beta.

After I followed all the necessary steps, I've ended up in this example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: IframeDemo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IframeDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyWidget();
  }
}

class MyWidget extends State<IframeDemo> {
  String _url;
  IFrameElement _iframeElement;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _url = 'https://flutter.dev/';
    _iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..src = _url
      ..id = 'iframe'
      ..style.border = 'none';
    //ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('url is $_url');

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 600,
          width: 600,
          child: HtmlElementView(
            viewType: 'iframeElement',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Sample Output:

[image]